# When should I use genitive personal pronouns versus possessive pronouns?

Tags: грамматика, падежи, родительный-падеж

In the phrase:

> дом Ивана

"Иван" is in the genitive, which means that the above translates to "Ivan's house". Following this pattern, if I wanted to say "my house", I should logically be able to do that by using я in the genitive:

> дом меня

However, in practice I always hear it as "мой дом". Is it *ever* possible to use "дом меня" to mean "my house"? If so, how is it different to "мой дом"?

Comment: Note: I feel like this might already have been asked, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: A related question was asked here: [Nominative possessive vs genitive possessive](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/8062/nominative-possessive-vs-genitive-possessive/).

Comment: I found that, but I don't think it's that related. That question is asking why we need to decline possessive pronouns, I'm asking how possessive pronouns are different from genitive personal pronouns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The English possessive pronouns are *always* rendered into Russian as the Russian possessive pronouns, *never* as the Russian personal pronouns in the Genitive case, just the same way as you would not say it in English '*the house of me'.
The function of the Russian personal pronouns in the Genitive case is

- to follow the prepositions that govern the Genitive case: **от меня**, **для тебя**, etc.
- to follow the verbs that govern the Genitive case: **Он боится меня**, **Я избегаю его**, etc.

Note, that the Genitive case forms of all the Russian personal pronouns coincides with their the Accusative case forms.

Answer (score 0):

No, it could be said only as a joke. You may think it like

- Possessive: Иванов дом = Ivan's house (OK); мой дом = my house (OK)
- Genitive: дом Ивана = house of Ivan (OK); дом меня = house of me (WRONG)

Comment: What form is "Иванов"?

Comment: @JackM - "Ивáнов" is a possessive adjective meaning "Ivan's", something like "Ivanian", like in English you have adjectives formed from proper nouns, like 'Shakespearean', 'Orwellian', etc.

Comment: @JackM This is possessive adjective. http://russkiyyazik.ru/721

Comment: @YellowSky "Shakespearean" = "шекспировский"; "Shakespear's" = "Шекспиров". These are different forms in Russian.

Comment: @user4419802 - Sure, still that's the closest English phenomenon to the Russian possessive adjectives.

Comment: I'd never heard of possessive adjectives. So is the genitive case *never* used to express ownership (of a possession by a person)? Is it only for properties of things and parts of things? (the top of the mountain, the handle of the cup, etc)

Comment: @JackM No, you may use genitive for both persons and things. On the other hand, possessive adjectives are for persons/animals only (except rare poetic samples, like "стёганье одеялово" etc.).

Comment: @user4419802 Well, if you use possessive pronouns for pronouns and possessive adjectives for proper nouns, what other situation is there in which you might express a person's ownership by the genitive?

Comment: @JackM Genitive is often used to denote the person's possession too. Saying which is more appropriate (genitive or poss. adj.) is a non-trivial question on its own.