# Was the genitive case of personal pronouns ever used to show possession?

Tags: история-языка, родительный-падеж

For example, nowadays, one might say `Собака женщины - большая`, but not `Собака меня - большая`(cf. [When should I use genitive personal pronouns versus possessive pronouns?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/10757/when-should-i-use-genitive-personal-pronouns-versus-possessive-pronouns)).

Was it ever historically correct to use the genitive case of personal pronouns in this context?

Answer (score 1):

While «собака меня большая» in the meaning of possession is impossible in Russian, besides «моя собака большая» you can say **«собака у меня большая»**, or **«у меня собака большая»** which shows  possession as well. It is the inversion of the well-known construction:
У меня (есть) большая собака.
But in general, don't expect that languages just copy each other. Each has got its own structure and its own way.

Answer (score 0):

> Was it ever historically correct to use the genitive declension of personal pronouns in this context?

Wiktionary [claims](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE) that third-person possessive pronouns его/её/их stem from genitive form of respective personal pronouns. There's no reference to any reliable source, though. No such claim is made for first- and second-person pronouns.